# cómo validar campos de entrada input de formulario de wordpress realizados con el plugin wpforms?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

deseo agregar una funcion a mi formulario de registro, que permita validar uno de los campos que es el siguiente : REFERIDO POR.

ejemplo: si el usuario "Stack" me refiere a la plataforma debo poner "Stack" en el campo.

la función debe validar que ese usuario exista y asú permitir el registro, en caso de que el usuario no exista debe dar error

Según la db el campo y sus valores son estos:

{"name":"Referido por:","value":"referido","id":12,"type":"text"},"4":

no poseo conocimientos en php como para resolver el problema por mi cuenta, el que pueda por favor ayudarme se lo agradecería mucho

Comment: Como te dijeron en la pregunta que acabas de eliminar, aca no se hace el trabajo por otras personas :(... revisaste la documentacion? que problema particular tuviste con lo que intentaste?

Comment: He visto tu web y ese formulario "insitu" y diria que tienes un problema de concepto.  Pones como campo obligatorio el campo **Referido** que tanto quieres verificar, y claro, eso va en contra tuya supongo, porque si yo quiero registrarme y no conozco a nadie ni vengo referido, entonces no podre.  O a malas me lo invento a ver si cuela, y si ya lo estuvieras validando, quizas hasta acertaria el nombre del referido. Piensa bien lo que quieres hacer alli, porque lo veo incómodo para nuevos usuarios, y peligroso si se equivocan de referido por similitud de nombres o porque se lo inventan

Comment: Aparte de eso, ya veo una posible solución a tu problema, pero no la voy a desarrollar, tan solo te dire como se podria hacer por pasos: 1) Crear un script en javascript propio 2) Invocarlo con el wordpress cuando aparezca ese formulario o siempre (eso ya es cosa tuya averiguar como) 3) En ese script poner al campo con el **name** `wpforms[fields][12]` a la escucha con addEventListener 4) Cuando se vaya rellenando ir verificando si existe el referido con ajax 5) Si no existe deshabilitar el boton "Registro" hasta que exista (pero ojo con referidos cortos y largos similares como juan y juan1)

Comment: es que esa es la idea, que todos los usuarios sean si o si referidos, ya que es una plataforma paga, con sistema de afiliados,  muchisimas gracias masterguru con tu ayuda realmente tengo un  norte para pensar la logica, me estaba realmente derritiendo el cerebro pensando como hacer esto!